# How to resolve 'Failed to minify the code from this file' error while running 'npm run build'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm-install, npm-scripts, date-fns

I am getting an error while running `npm run build`. It was running before, there were no new changes in the package.json file still it will fail. Below is the error that I got
[image]

I searched for this error and checked the react-scripts version (2.0.5) it is greater than 2.0.0

Can anyone provide me the appropriate answer for this error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something happened in 2.29 which changed Parser.js.  I reverted to 2.28.0 and seemed to work

Comment: Hi
Can you please provide some more details on this, I am not getting for which dependency I need to change the version from 2.29 to 2.28.0.

Answer (score 0):

Change the package date-fns to version 2.28 in package.json.

```
"date-fns": "2.28.0"
```

Then this error should go away.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @WofloW.